# Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scikit-image/scikit-image-0.11.2.tar.gz

Tags: software-installation

I try to install scikit-image on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
pip install -U scikit-image
```

I get this error:

```
Collecting scikit-image
  Downloading scikit-image-0.11.2.tar.gz (18.6MB)
    34% |###########                     | 6.5MB 83kB/s eta 0:02:25
  Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scikit-image/scikit-image-0.11.2.tar.gz#md5=9a2118cc4d18c038a7d22e3ce0141309 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-image/) (d92e68a3277e7d75b472991cfc6806a0) doesn't match the expected hash 9a2118cc4d18c038a7d22e3ce0141309!
  Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scikit-image/scikit-image-0.11.2.tar.gz#md5=9a2118cc4d18c038a7d22e3ce0141309 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-image/)
```

I run again the above command, but I get this error over and over:

```
Collecting scikit-image
  Using cached scikit-image-0.11.2.tar.gz
  Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scikit-image/scikit-image-0.11.2.tar.gz#md5=9a2118cc4d18c038a7d22e3ce0141309 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-image/) (d92e68a3277e7d75b472991cfc6806a0) doesn't match the expected hash 9a2118cc4d18c038a7d22e3ce0141309!
  Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scikit-image/scikit-image-0.11.2.tar.gz#md5=9a2118cc4d18c038a7d22e3ce0141309 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-image/)
begueradj@begueradj-Sampo:~$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Removing Pip cache

- `rm -rf ~/.pip/cache/`
- `sudo rm -rf /root/.pip/cache`

Or just run `pip` without using the cache:

- `--no-cache-dir`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510610/416646)

### Bad Pip?

1. Which version of `pip` are you running?

   - `pip --version`
   - `pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`
2. Upgrade `pip`

   - `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

### Bad Internet/MitM?

I've just downloaded the file and verified:

```
9a2118cc4d18c038a7d22e3ce0141309  scikit-image-0.11.2.tar.gz
```

Which means you didn't download the complete file, the correct file, or something is specifically injecting a bad file.

Comment: pip 6.0.8 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
`

Comment: How can I delete the cached file ?

Comment: to rmove the pip cache, the first option with the 2 instructions did not work, but the second one works. I am waiting until the installation finishes, if everything is ok i will accept your answer, for the moment i just upvote. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: The first option and second option depend upon which user is using pip (ie: Your user, or the root user).